# how to make img link to a simple code (Html and Css)

Tags: html, css, web, hyperlink

so i want to make all my img links into a simple word/code in html and css

Example:

//Not like this

`<img src="https://img1.com">`

`<img src="https://img2.com">`

`<img src="https://img3.com">`

//I want to do something a little bit more like this instead

value01 = https://img1.com

value02 = https://img2.com

value03 = https://img3.com

`<img src="value01">`

`<img src="value02">`

`<img src="value03">`

I don't know what to do I am new to HTML and CSS

Comment: so its just like simple redirect ? you can just make another `.php` file that has the list of your img list and put the link in your value01 using `a` tag. but i dont see any purpose why you do this way

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this in html because
The `<img>` tag is used to embed an image in an HTML page, maybe you can do this in `python`, instead, you can do this:

```html
<b>
 <img src="value1.jpg" alt="Value1" >
</b>
```

Source :
[img tag html](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways I can think of.

::THIS FIRST OPTION ONLY WORKS IF YOU SAVE THE PAGE IN (.PHP) EXTENSION

1° Method => You can create a php file apart, store the links of images in variables like this.

< ? php

$img = 'https : // upload . wikimedia . org /wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Python-logo-notext . svg/1200px-Python-logo-notext . svg . png';

? >

next, you can call this file in the main page/index.

< ? php

include ". /page/images . php";

? >

< html >

< img src="< ? php echo $img; ? >" alt="" srcset="">

< / html >

---

2° Method => you can just save the image to a folder easy to target.

- create a folder inside the same folder you are accessing your main page.
  for example: I created a folder called (img) in the same folder my index.html is found, save the image with a short name.

so to access that image i would call the image like this

< img src="image/img.png" alt="" srcset="">

Comment: Your answer needs better formatting, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help on writing clear and well-formatted answers 